# django-registration: Cannot translate email and subject

Tags: internationalization, django-registration

Any **.html** template for django-registration module works fine with `{% blocktrans %}` and `{% trans %}` template blocks. With `{% load i18n %}` in place, of course.

But I cannot make use of i18n tags in **activation_email.txt** and **activation_email_subject.txt** templates. Strings marked for translation just don't appear in **.po** file after `makemessages`.

Also, when wrapping a text with `{% blocktrans %}{% endblocktrans %}`, all variables such as `{{ site.domain }}` and `{{ site.name }}` are not processed.

Can you suggest what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was my bad, I just improperly used `makemessages`. [By default it processes only .html files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---extension).

In my case

```
django-admin.py makemessages -a -e html,txt
```

does all the work.

As for variables, `{% blocktrans %}{% endblocktrans %}` cannot process variables inside object, so we have to retrieve them before translation:

```
{% blocktrans with site.name as site_name and site.domain as site_domain %}
```

Good examples of templates for django-registration are given [here](https://github.com/dokterbob/django-registration-templates/blob/master/registration_templates/templates/registration/activation_email.txt).